# 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Tags: kotlin, android-activity, fragment, bottomnavigationview

Unable to load my application , it displays null pointer exception
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at com.example.android.bettingapp.DashboardActivity.onCreate(DashboardActivity.kt:27)

> DashboardActivity

```
class DashboardActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var dashboardBinding: ActivityDashboardBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    dashboardBinding = ActivityDashboardBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(dashboardBinding.root)
    setSupportActionBar(myToolBar)
    supportActionBar?.hide()
    val navView: BottomNavigationView = dashboardBinding.bottomNavView
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.homeFragment,
            R.id.newBoastFragment,
            R.id.myBoastFragment,
            R.id.profileFragment
        )
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    supportActionBar?.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
}
```

}

Comment: Though its late, how about commenting this line of code ------------
 setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration).
#PS. I tried so and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check the app theme in **styles.xml**, for example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Maybe the problem is you could be using an `AppCompat` theme.

If you want to use `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` and you extend your activity with `AppCompatActivity` then you need to use an `AppCompat` theme to avoid this issue.

For example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Hope this works.

Comment: <style name="Theme.BettingApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"> this my style theme but it didn't work @Shailendra Madda

Comment: That is the issue then, you made it NoActionBar but trying to `supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`. Just change your theme to `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` as I mentioned above.

Comment: But I should remove this toolbar in my app and I need to create a custom toolbarr. That's why I gave this NoActionBar

Comment: Can you check what is the code at this line number `DashboardActivity.kt:27`?

Comment: setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

Comment: The exception you mentioned and the line number you mentioned are not matching. Run the application once again and share the log trace along with other supporting files code.

Comment: 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference        at com.example.android.bettingapp.DashboardActivity.onCreate(DashboardActivity.kt:33)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237632/discussion-between-pavi-subramanyam-and-shailendra-madda).